# Is there a way to run Azure Pipelines configurations locally to see their output?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a sample yaml file that I need to get running, I can see it runs in Azure Pipelines but how do I run it locally to test it out on my computer?

Tried powershell, docker, libraries that parse YAML, but none run the file such as yaml.load(some sample text)

```
steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```

What I expect to see, is a window titled Run a one-line script that says hello world! on it, yet I can't seem to run this, I could use IIS to run this file if that is possible.

Comment: YAML isn't an executable format at all. What you have is a different format built *on top of* YAML, just like shell scripts are built *on top of* plain text, or OOXML files are built *on top of* XML -- but a text editor doesn't know how to run a script, and an XML editor doesn't know what font text in an OOXML file is supposed to be rendered in. Same thing here: A generic YAML parser isn't expected to know what Azure does on top of the format.

Comment: ...so, what you want to know is not how to run "YAML files", but how to run "Azure Pipelines configuration files", or such. If there's a more specific/well-known format name, perhaps the Azure documentation describes it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there a way to run Azure Pipelines configurations locally to see their output?

Agree with Charles.

I am afraid there is no such a way to run Azure Pipelines configurations locally.

As we know, the YAML is the configuration file for Azure pipeline, which could not be executed separately from the Azure pipeline. If you leave the compiler, the YAML file will not be recognized, for example, the copy task:

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files'
  inputs:
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
```

The YAML syntax is very simple, but if we do not use the Azure pipeline, Other compilers will not be able to parse this syntax unless we develop a compiler like Azure pipeline.

Besides, I know that if we want to make sure YAML file is working before submitting it to the Repos. we may need takes a lot of trials/failures to submit, until I am correct, it is a very painful thing. Many other users have the same request, there is an user voice about it:

[Ability to test YAML builds locally](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/366517/ability-to-test-yaml-builds-locally.html)

You could  vote and add your comments for this feedback. When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this, I will give feedback on this link